# install brother scanner ads-2000e on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, software-installation, printing

Brother has the instruction for installing the driver here: http://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadhowto.aspx?c=us_ot&lang=en&prod=ads2000e_us&os=128&dlid=dlf006645_000&flang=4&type3=566. And I ran

```
sudo dpkg -i --force-all brscan4-0.4.4-4.amd64.deb
```

to install the driver and it seemed to have installed. But when I try to connect and see the scanner it does not come up. How do I make it work?

Comment: *How* did you try and connect?

Comment: through the usb cable